# Render partial views located on remote server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a server that holds some partial view files.
How i can to load files to Html.Partial from another server ?
Like:

```
@Html.Partial("http://localhost/PartialServer/view/calculator.cshtml");
```

Can i override the partial to load it from url ?

Asp.net MVC is the framework.

Comment: Will the remote Url actually return the full Razor code?

Comment: No, i will configure the repository server to serve this file type.

Comment: I assume the answer is 'yes' then. Requesting the Url will indeed return to full Razor code...

Comment: I think it's not possible with this method. how i can override Partial to handle remore url ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, create a new directory named `_RemotePartialsCache` under your `~/Views/` folder.

Extend `HtmlHelper` with a `RemotePartial` method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private const string _remotePartialsPath = "~/Views/_RemotePartialsCache/";
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> _remotePartialsMappingCache = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    public static MvcHtmlString RemotePartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string partialUrl, object model = null)
    {
        string cachedPath;

        // return cached copy if exists
        if (_remotePartialsMappingCache.TryGetValue(partialUrl, out cachedPath))
            return helper.Partial(_remotePartialsPath + cachedPath, model);

        // download remote data
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var partialUri = new Uri(partialUrl);
        var partialData = webClient.DownloadString(partialUrl);

        // save cached copy locally
        var partialLocalName = Path.ChangeExtension(partialUri.LocalPath.Replace('/', '_'), "cshtml");
        var partialMappedPath = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(_remotePartialsPath + partialLocalName);
        File.WriteAllText(partialMappedPath, partialData);

        // save to cache
        _remotePartialsMappingCache[partialUrl] = partialLocalName;

        return helper.Partial(_remotePartialsPath + partialLocalName, model);
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
@Html.RemotePartial("http://localhost/PartialServer/view/calculator.cshtml")
```

You can also replace the original `Partial` method with the above implementation (that will get to work only when the passed path is a remote url) but it's not recommended.

Comment: +1 very clever solution. I would also add a way to reset cache.

Comment: @MiBu, Thanks. I agree there should be a way to control cache. Exceptions handling is probably also needed, I only wanted to deliver core functionality.